# C++ object parameters confusion

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

I'm having an issue passing an object as an argument for one of my functions(I think).
In one of my classes called Engine.cpp, I call a function from another class called knight.cpp. Below is the code for both.

**Engine.cpp**

```
void Engine::player_controling(N5110 &lcd,Gamepad &pad)
{
   knight.draw(lcd); //draws the knight in the starting position
}
```

**Knight.cpp**

```
void Knight::init() //starting postion for the knight
{
    x_knight=42;             //X-cordinate for the knight
    y_knight=33;             //Y-cordinate for the knight
}


void Knight::draw(N5110 &lcd) //draws the knight in the start pos
{
  const int man[17][13] =  {      //the array for the knight, 1=pixel turn on.
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    };
    //draws the knight
    lcd.drawSprite(x_knight,y_knight,17,13,(int *)man);
}
```

In main.cpp, if i directly call

```
knight.draw(lcd);
```

Then it draws the knight in the correct position as it takes x_knight as 42 and y_knight as 33 from

```
knight.init()
```

However calling this in main.cpp

```
Engine.player_controling(lcd & pad);
```

means that it sets

```
x_knight=0
y_knight=0
```

which are the default values.
How do I get Engine.player_controlling(lcd &pad); 
to recognise knight.init as the correct values?

Comment: The code looks incomplete - where do you call `knight.init()` ? How does the `knight` object gets constructed inside `Engine` class (if it's a class member) ? Basically you need to ensure that `Init()` is called for the `Knight` class before the function call of `player_controling()`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `Init()` function is not called before`Engine::player_controling()` is called.

One possible solution could be - you need to ensure that `Knight::Init()` is called before the function call of `Engine::player_controling()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on those code snippets and the behavior, I would guess that you have multiple Knight instances.

probably, the instance owned by Engine is not the one, you're calling init for.

It should be something like:

```
class Engine {
 public:
  // You have to initialize Knight inside your Engine.
  Engine() {
    knight_.Init(); // This is (I guess) the missing part.
  }
  // Alternatively, you may want to pass an already initialized knight here.
  Engine(const Knight& knight) : knight_(knight) {}
  // ...
  void PlayerControlling(N5110 &lcd,Gamepad &pad) {
    knight_.Draw();
  }
 private:
  Knight knight_;
};
```